# Count of non-NULL values in a column, for every column in a table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Essentially, I want to know how many values there are in every column of a table.  I'd like to be able to do this for every table in a database.  I can't figure out how to do it in SQL or in Python. Either would be helpful.

Suppose this data is in a table 'customer':

| id | firstname | surname | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | joe | blogs | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | jane | doe | (null) | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | bobby | tables | (null) | (null) | 4 |

I'd like a query that would return:

| table | id | count_non_null_vals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer | firstname | 3 |
| customer | surname | 3 |
| customer | val1 | 1 |
| customer | val2 | 2 |
| customer | val3 | 3 |

Comment: This is common "unpivot" output table - use either conditional aggregation or multiple UNION. If you want the list of tables and their columns names to be gathered dynamically then you'd use stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go outside of SQL first.

In the client (python should work fine) you run a query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM customer
```

This will give you list of columns. Based on this list you can construct a query, one per field:

```
select
  count( distinct Field )
from customer
```

And run it in the loop for each field.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL server you can run

```
select count(ColumnName).
```

This will give you the number of all records that the column has any value.  Notice that if you'll use the

```
count(distinct ColumnNmae)
```

it will give the number of unique values without nulls so if a value will be returned more then one time, it will be counted only once.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a PROCEDURE Get_count_non_null_vals

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Get_count_non_null_vals` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Get_count_non_null_vals`(in _Db varchar(255))
BEGIN

SELECT group_concat(concat('select \'', C.Table_Name, '\' T,\'', C.Column_Name, '\' F, count(`', C.Column_Name, '`) C from ', C.Table_Name, ' where `', C.Column_Name, '` is not null') SEPARATOR ' union all ')
into @SQLText
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
join information_schema.`TABLES` T on T.Table_name=C.Table_name and T.table_Schema=C.table_Schema
where C.table_Schema=_Db and extra<>'auto_increment';

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLText;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

After that:

```
call Get_count_non_null_vals(YourDatabaseName);
```